# DELETE ROW command is getting skipped without any ERROR

Tags: php

I have two tables, table1 has multiple rows with data, while table2 is empty.

I m trying to perform a simple INSET into and DELETE command in php to add the selected row from table1 to table2 and at the same time DELETE the selected row from table1

But here, it gets inserted to table 2 and doesn't get deleted from table 1 but returns to main page without any error.

My code as follows:

Calling row content from table1 to user page:

```
<?php 
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM apromocode ";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {                               
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>          
        <tr >
            <form id="promocodesub" action="apromocodesubdelete.php" method="post">
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($row2["id"]); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($row2["code"]); ?>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" form="promocodesub" name="code" value="<?php echo ($row2["code"]); ?>"/>
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($row2["occation"]); ?>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" form="promocodesub" name="occation" value="<?php echo ($row2["occation"]); ?>"/>
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($row2["about"]); ?>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" form="promocodesub" name="about" value="<?php echo ($row2["about"]); ?>"/>
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($row2["discount"]); ?>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" form="promocodesub" name="discount" value="<?php echo ($row2["discount"]); ?>"/>
                <td>
                    <?php echo ($row2["date"]); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button form="promocodesub" type="submit" name="deleteId" value="<?php echo ($row2["id"])?>"class="promocodedelete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>  
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

So, when user open the page, he will see all row contents lined up in sequence along with "delete" button for each. When the user presses the delete button for that particular row, it will get inserted to table2 and should get deleted from the table1 with the following script:

```
<?php include('amerchantassign.php'); ?>
<?php
$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "";
$code = $_POST['code'];
$occation = $_POST['occation'];
$about = $_POST['about'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
enter code here

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$deleteId= $_POST['deleteId'];

$sql="INSERT INTO apromocodehistory (code, occation, about, discount, date)
SELECT code, occation, about, discount, date
FROM   apromocode 
WHERE  id=  $deleteId";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql4 = "DELETE FROM feedback WHERE id = '$deleteId' ";

    if ($conn->query($sql4) === TRUE) {
        echo '<a href="amerchantassign.php"></a>';
    } else {
        echo "ERROR" . $sql4;
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Any Suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: I will happen all the time. You are doing it wrongly. While deleting pass the Id of that row to delete function and then get that Id in you submit action and then apply select operation in `table 1` fetch result and insert it into `second table`

Comment: all your forms have same `id` . so yes it should take the last one. This is what you call confusing the browser.

Comment: You must specify the `id` of Table 1 select that and than `INSERT` in table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<td><button form="promocodesub" type="submit" name="deleteId" value="<?php echo ($row2["id"]) ?>" class="promocodedelete">Delete</button></td>
```

After submit

```
$deleteId= $_POST['deleteId'];
```

Apply select on above Id and then apply delete operation.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO apromocodehistory (code, occation, about, discount, date)
      SELECT code, occation, about, discount, date
      FROM   apromocode 
      WHERE  id=  $deleteId";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo '<a href="amerchantassign.php"></a>';
 }
 else {
 echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

Comment: Still unable to insert the selected one?

Comment: No, INSERt worked fine. this time i tried to add another command DELETE in the same page, it kinda skips it without any error.. i have updated the question , please take a look..

Comment: Do you want to delete it from `feedback` or `apromocode`?

Comment: But I am still confuse. You are selected from **apromocode** inserting into **apromocodehistory** and deleting from **feedback**. What is the relation of feedback?. Still try this code `$sql4 = "DELETE FROM feedback WHERE id = $deleteId ";`